# What happens when mv command for rename is interrupted

Tags: linux, bash

I like to use `mv` command to rename a file within the same filesystem but what happens when the process gets interrupted? Example:

```
mv file1.txt file2.txt
```

Both file1.txt and file2.txt will be on the same directory. AFAIK file1.txt gets renamed as file2.txt and file2.txt's memory range blocks gets marked as free. So when it gets interrupted, will there be both files named file2.txt? But linux/unix won't allow that right?

Comment: It can't be interrupted; `mv` performs an atomic system call. Either the interrupt happens before the *name* `file2` is added to the directory, or it happens *after* `file2` and been created and `file1` is removed. The OS itself ensures that nothing can happen *between* those two events.

Comment: Consider `ln file1.txt file2.txt`.  There's no reason not to allow a directory to have two entries  that both refer to the same file.

Comment: Often, we say "file named file2.txt", but that isn't really accurate.  There is no file named "file2.txt", because files don't have names.  "file2.txt" is an entry in the directory that refers to a file.  If "file1.txt" is another entry in the directory  that refers to the same file, there's no conflict.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `There's no reason not to allow a directory to have two entries that both refer to the same file` file1.txt will be a tmp file which will have an updated content than file2.txt. Whenever file1.txt gets updated it has to immediately gets renamed as file2.txt, so that file2.txt will always have updated content. Example:  `sample.txt and sample_tmp.txt`

Comment: Whenever file write happens, it has to be done in sample_tmp.txt and gets renamed as sample.txt. Python process will use contents from sample.txt.

Comment: Also what happens when read by python and mv happens simultaneously? Will the python process gets an updated content from sample.txt or there'll be an exception thrown? As python opens sample.txt for read and mv renames sample_tmp.txt to sample.txt which frees up sample.txt's memory, So will python process get an exception or empty file content?